# Injecting JSON parameter in nativeQuery

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

This works when

```
@Query(
  value = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE school = :schoolId AND details @> '{\"id\":\"1234\",\"name\":\"John\"}'", 
  nativeQuery = true
)
```

I am passing `@Param("schoolId") String schoolId`

But when I pass the JSON as a param, it fails with

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException, could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb @> character varying
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE school = :schoolId AND details @> :details", nativeQuery = true)

@Param("schoolId") String schoolId, @Param("details") String details
```

Comment: Please show us the real exception, which `cause`d the `SQLGrammarException` (which is at the end of the cause chain). We can only guess without it. -- But my best bet is that spring+jdbc binds the `@Param("details") String details` parameter as a `VARCHAR`. It is usually hard to work with JDBC, if you want to use some non-conventional types, such as `uuid` or `json[b]`. Simply adding the `stringtype=unspecified` [JDBC DSN parameter](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters) to your connection string can avoid a lot of headaches.

Comment: ... or you could just use an explicit cast, like `details @> CAST(:details AS json[b])`, but that is rather unpleasant IMHO.

Comment: @pozs you are correct, it did work after typecasting it as CAST(:details AS jsonb). If you can post the same as the answer, I will accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring+JDBC binds Strings as `VARCHAR` by default. The cheap solution here is to use cast(s):

```
details @> CAST(:details AS jsonb)
```

But, if you have a lot of queries, in which some non-standard types are used as parameters & you want to bind their String representation, you can use the

```
stringtype=unspecified
```

[JDBC DSN parameter](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters) in your connection string. That way, every parameter, which is bound by `setString()` will have an `unknown` type in PostgreSQL, thus it will try to infer their actual types.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this.

Just in addition to the solution, you can also do the cast as:

`details @> :details::jsonb`

I'm using version 11 of postgres, not sure when it was introduced.